# Is it possible to perform strict validation of kubernetes manifests in vscode?

Tags: validation, kubernetes, visual-studio-code

I've got an (invalid) kubernetes manifest:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: foo
  labels:
    app: foo
spec:
  poarts:
  - name: http
    protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPoart: 80
  selector:
    app: foo
```

I can validate this manifest with kubeconform:

```bash
> docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/src ghcr.io/yannh/kubeconform:master -strict /src/foo-service.yaml
/src/foo-service.yaml - Service foo is invalid: For field spec: Additional property poarts is not allowed
```

I'd like to validate this manifest in vscode.

1. I already have the official Kubernetes (v1.3.11) and Red Hat YAML (v1.12.2) extensions installed.
2. I've tried specifying the strict schema in settings.json:

```json
    "yaml.schemas": {
        "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yannh/kubernetes-json-schema/master/v1.24.9-standalone-strict/service-v1.json": ["*-service.yaml", "*-service.yml"],
        "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yannh/kubernetes-json-schema/master/v1.24.9-standalone-strict/deployment-apps-v1.json": ["*-deployment.yaml", "*-deployment.yml"],
        "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yannh/kubernetes-json-schema/master/v1.24.9-standalone-strict/configmap-v1.json": ["*-configmap.yaml", "*-configmap.yml"],
        ...
        "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datreeio/CRDs-catalog/main/argoproj.io/application_v1alpha1.json": ["app-of-apps.yaml", "*-app-of-apps.yml", "/app-of-apps/*.yaml", "/app-of-apps/*.yml"],
        "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datreeio/CRDs-catalog/main/monitoring.coreos.com/servicemonitor_v1.json": ["*-servicemonitor.yaml", "*-servicemonitor.yml"]
```

But
a) this is hugely cumbersome, and b) immediately after editing settings.json I get the red squiggly and the error listed under "PROBLEMS", but then when I close and re-open my yaml file, the validations go away. It looks like the Kubernetes extension is auto-detecting the schema and overriding the settings in settings.json.

Can I strictly validate kubernetes manifests in vscode in a manner similar to the `-strict` flag in kubeconform?